# Authorize WebApp to ADFS in order to access Dynamics CRM Web API

Tags: authorization, dynamics-crm, token, adfs, dynamics-365

I have a web application that needs to speak with Dynamics CRM 365 Web API. The Dynamics CRM is configured as a Relying Party on ADFS.
The server is Windows Server 2016 and everything is on premise and not on Azure.

What I did to acquire a valid token are the following:

1) In ADFS went to Application Groups and add an new Server Application, took the ClientID and also generate a Client Secret for my web application.

[image]

2) Add new new user in Active Directory the webAppUser

3) Add this user as **an Application User in CRM** with Application ID the ClientID I got earlier when I registered my web app to ADFS. Also created a new Role with full permissions on Entity Account and assign this role to this Application User

4) I'm using the below code to retrieve a bearer token and add it to my HttpClient Authorization header.

```
public class CrmWebApiClient
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CrmWebApiClient()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://crmbaseaddress.com");            
    }

    internal async Task Initialize()
    {
        try
        {               
            var authority = "https://adfsServerUrl/adfs/";
            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,false);
            var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientID,clientSecret);

            var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync("https://crmbaseaddress.com", credentials);

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
                new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex;
        }

    }

    internal async Task<string> GetValuesAsync()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            result = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync("api/data/v8.1/accounts");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var error = ex;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

5) I manage to get a token but when I call the CRM's Web Api I still get 401 Unauthorized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end i had to use a system user and send it's credentials in my oAUth request using the code below in order to acquire a valid token:

```
namespace TestApp.App_Start {
public class CrmWebApiClient
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public CrmWebApiClient()
    {       
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
        _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://crmUrl");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-MaxVersion","4.0");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
    }

    internal async Task Initilize()
    {
        try
        {

            var tokenClient = new HttpClient();             
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] {
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("client_id",_clientID),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("client_secret",_clientSecret),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("resource",_urlOfResource),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("username",_usernameOfSystemUser),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("password",_passwordOfSystemUser),
                new KeyValuePair<string,string>("grant_type","password"),
            });
            var res = tokenClient.PostAsync("https://adfsUrl/adfs/oauth2/token", content);
            var respo = res.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            var accesstoken = JObject.Parse(respo).GetValue("access_token").ToString();

            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Exception when requesting the bearer token from ADFS: {ex.Message} - {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
        }

    }

    internal async Task<string> GetAccountsAsync()
    {
        var result = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            result = _httpClient.GetStringAsync("/api/data/v8.0/accounts").Result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.WriteLine($"Exception when calling the CRM api: {ex.Message} - {ex.InnerException?.Message}");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
}


// Use the above class like that
var httpClient = new CrmWebApiClient();
httpClient.Initilize().Wait();
var result = httpClient.GetAccountsAsync().Result;
```

Comment: What version of ADFS is this? Are password grants supported..obviously there are, but could you clarify a little bit more.

Comment: @davidcarr it's Windows Server 2016 with the latest ADFS

Comment: @RickyStam I have a similar situation, could you clarify what you mean by system user? Aren't all users user created?

Comment: @tracertong i mean that i created a user in AD that doesn't belong to any real user, but only use his username and password in my application. That's why i call him system user.